# Why is ofstream not creating a file if I execute my .exe ouside of Visual Studio?

Tags: file, visual-studio-2013, ifstream, ofstream

So, I have a class called Settings:

```
void Settings::load(){

std::ifstream ini_file("settings.ini");

if (ini_file.is_open()){
    // TODO: Read this checking correctness
    std::string buffer;
    char buffer2;

    ini_file >> buffer;
    ini_file >> width;
    ini_file >> buffer2;

    ini_file >> buffer;
    ini_file >> height;
    ini_file >> buffer2;

    ini_file >> buffer;
    ini_file >> fullscreen;
    ini_file >> buffer2;

    ini_file.close();
}
else
    save();
}

void Settings::save(){

std::ofstream ini_file("settings.ini");

ini_file << "width= " << width << ";\n"
    << "height= " << height << ";\n"
    << "fullscreen= " << fullscreen << ";\n";

ini_file.close();
}
```

In theory, this should check if settings.ini exists and if it doesnt, it creates it with the default values of settings. Now, this works if I execute it under Visual Studio, and it creates the settings.ini in the project folder, but if I copy my executable to another folder and execute it manually (double clicking on it), it does not create any file.

Why is this happening?

Thank you!

Comment: It probably depends where you're running the executable from.  You may not have permission to create files there or they may be redirected to a different place by [file virtualization](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/927387).  You'll need to provide some more details about where you're running it from.

Comment: I created a folder inside the VS project and copied the exe in there.

Comment: What is the full pathname of that folder?  You should edit your question to include a short complete example so we can see what you're doing.